# Symfony2 backend datetime yml validatiion

Tags: validation, yaml

I've been trying to validate a datetime field using yml (validation.yml) file. Though it validates the "DateTime Type" it doesn't validate "Null" or "Blank". I've tried using NotBlank and NotNull.

```
  expirationStartDate:
        - DateTime: ~
        - NotBlank: ~

    expirationEndDate:
        - DateTime: ~
        - NotBlank: ~
```